# Необходимо сделать отображение содержания одного div поверх других в CSS

Tags: css

```css
#cookie_notification{
  display: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 90%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
```

Необходимо сделать отображение содержания одного `div` поверх других в CSS.

Не помогает:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999999999999999;
```

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, Ваш блок #cookie_notification находится в каком-то дочернем элементе, у которого стоит свой z-index. Вытащите его сразу после body, например, и попробуйте.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо! Всё заработало.

Comment: @yarik.moslife если Вам помог мой ответ - пометьте его, пожалуйста, как верный ) Галочка слева.

Comment: Интересно, но на другом сайте стало хуже, блок спрятался ещё глубже за элементами.

Comment: z-index: 9999999999999999; - вот так обычно не делают. ) Стоит этот параметр по сайту делать контролируемо, и понимая какой самый верхний. Усновно говоря z-index: 1000, вряд ли у вас есть какой-то слой больше. Возможно у Вас там есть какой-то блок, который еще выше стоит, мы же не видим какой код там написан. Однозначно такие блоки надо или сразу после body ставить, или в самом низу перед. При этом, если этот блок должен быть всегда на экране - position: fixed, чтобы он зафиксировался и "вырвался" из структуры кода наверх.

Comment: Ну, это я психанут, максимум, что я нашёл это z-index:102

Comment: Нужно индивидуально смотреть на сайт уже и искать причину там :)

Comment: Извините, я не готов за Вас делать работу и разбираться в Вашем коде :)  В рамках данного топика - точно могу сказать что надо копать стили сайта. )

Comment: Это, да, не надо :) Спасибо, с одним сайтом решение сработало на 100 процентов. Буду рыть в остальных.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cookie_notification > *{
  z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
```

*Но это костыль)*

---

Попробуйте выбрать более конкретный сss-селектор. n-child селекторы бы больше подошли. Посмотрите в доках СSS3, это должно помочь.